# Unserializing array of objects

Tags: php

I have a scenario like this to dump dynamically objects to the session and retrieve back all the objects back but seems like some where I am doing wrong.

Here is the snippet for serializing objects to session

`$CMO` is an object.

```
$SerializedCmo = serialize($CMO);
if(isset($_SESSION['count']))
{
    $count = $_SESSION['count'] ;
    $count++;
}
else
    $count = 0;

$_SESSION['count'] = $count;

$_SESSION[$CaseAssignID.$count] = $SerializedCmo;
```

Here is the snippet for unserializing objects from session

```
$count =  $_SESSION['count'];
$CaseAssignId = $_SESSION['assignmentvalue'];

$CMO = new Condition_Management_Information();

for ($i =0 ; $i <= $count ; $i++)
{
  $UnserializedCmo = $_SESSION[$CaseAssignId.$i];
  $CMO = unserialize($UnserializedCmo);

}
```

Values for count and CaseassignId are proper but var_dump for $UnserializedCmo and $CMO are NULL and boolean(false) respectively.

Comment: Suggestion, avoid using same id. as functions, like "count", sooner or later, may get mixed up. Use "objcount" or "howmany" as an examples.

Comment: What is the meaning of "$_SESSION[$CaseAssignID.$count]", you are using that at the serializaton method, but not at the deserialization code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
function SerializeTest()
{
    /* Condition_Management_Information */ $CMO = GetObjectFromSomewhere();

    $CaseAssignID = GetIDPrefixFromSomeWhere();

    $SerializedCmo = serialize($CMO);

    // get current qty of items
    if(isset($_SESSION['howmany']))
    {
        $howmany = (int)$_SESSION['howmany'] ;
    }
    else
        $howmany = (int)0;

    // increment qty
    $howmany++;    
    $_SESSION['howmany'] = $howmany;

    $SessionID = $CaseAssignID . "_" . $howmany;

    $_SESSION[$SessionID] = $SerializedCmo;
} // function SerializeTest(....)
```

And the other method:

```
function DeserializeTest()
{
    // ALWAYS use a cast for integer objects, otherwise you'll get a NULL value,
    // instead of a ZERO value
    $howmany = (int)$_SESSION['howmany'];

    // $CaseAssignId = $_SESSION['assignmentvalue'];    
    $CaseAssignID = GetIDPrefixFromSomeWhere();

    // do not need to do this:
    // $CMO = new Condition_Management_Information();

    /* Condition_Management_Information */ $CMO = null;

    for ($i =0 ; $i <= $howmany ; $i++)
    {
      $SessionID = $CaseAssignID . "_" . $i;

      // verify objects from session
      // maybe the error is here
        if(isset($_SESSION[$SessionID]))
        {
            $UnserializedCmo = $_SESSION[$SessionID];

                    // do not assume something is stored
                    if ($UnserializedCmo != null)
                    {
              $CMO = unserialize($UnserializedCmo);
              DoSomethingWithEachObject($CMO);
                    }
        }
        else
            $CMO = null;
    } // for
} // function DeserializeTest(....)
```

Cheers

Comment: The code looks more cleaner now but the logic seems same.I was wondering why "$UnserializedCmo = $_SESSION[$CaseAssignId.$i];" is returning NULL to me.Anyways I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Yup this is working.Looks like conversion from string to int seems working.

Comment: @user3443398 : tdlr; (1) $_SESSION sometimes returns null, have to cast, (2) cast $_SESSION in order to avoid null when you want 0 or empty string, o false for booleans

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a class for the object to serialize and include it before serialize and unserialize:

```
//script.php
include "objectClass.php"
$obj= new objectClass(a,b,c);
$_SESSION['something'] = serialize($obj);

//other_script.php
include "objectClass.php"
$obj= unserialize($_SESSION['something']);
echo $obj->getA();
```

Regards.

Comment: Actually I haven't put all the code here.What ever you have pointed out is already existing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested code:

I suggest that you append the  '$SerializedCmo' to an array called 'SerializedCmo'.

That way you do not have to bother knowing the index of it.

Here is the snippet for serializing objects to session

```
$SerializedCmo = serialize($CMO);
if (!isset($_SESSION['SerializedCmo']))
{
  $_SESSION['SerializedCmo'] = array();
}


$_SESSION['SerializedCmo'][] = $SerializedCmo; // append to array...
```

Here is the snippet for unserializing objects from session

```
$CMO = new Condition_Management_Information();

$allCMO = array(); // unserialized objects in here

if (isset($_SESSION['SerializedCmo']))
{
   foreach ($_SESSION['SerializedCmo'] as $SerializedCmo)
   {
     $AllCMO[] = unserialize($SerializedCmo); // append to CMO object array


   }
}
```

Comment: yup I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: array is also working but I am not planning for the generic counter to use.